# int and string errors in the class file in Python

Tags: python, string, class, python-3.x, methods

I am writing a python program where I have 3 files. One is the main file, one is the class file and one is data file. The data file reads from 2 text files and splits and arranges the data for use by the class and main file. Anyways, I am pretty much done with the data and main files but I am having problems with the class file. Its a general string formatting issue but I am failing to understand what I can possibly do to fix it. I am getting the error

> "  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Program 6/FINAL/classFile.py", line 83,
>   in **repr**
>       if len(self._birthDay[0])<2: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: Is `self._birthDay` a string? and when are u getting this error?

Comment: You should probably avoid modifying the object in a `__repr__` method, other than updating some cache or something.

Comment: I have updated and added my main and data files for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like `birthDay` is a list of ints, not a list of strings.

If you want to make sure they're all strings, you can try:

```
self._birthDay = list(map(str, birthDay))
```

Alternatively, if you *know* that they are all strings, you can use string formatting in the first place to avoid these `len` checks:

```
self._birthDay = ['{:02d}'.format(x) for x in birthDay]
```

Even better, though, would be to represent `birthDay` as a `datetime.datetime` object. Assuming it always comes in as 3 ints, Month, Day, Year, you'd do:

```
bmon, bday, byear = birthDay
self._birthDay = datetime.datetime(byear, bmon, bday)
```

Then your `__repr__` can make use of the [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) method.

**Edit**

In response to your update, I think you should add `from datetime import datetime` to the top of `getData`, then instead of parsing out the month/day/year, use:

```
birthDay = datetime.strptime(x[3], '%m/%d/%Y')
```

This will get you a full-fledged `datetime` object to represent the birthdate (alternatively, you can use a `datetime.date` object, since you don't need the time).

Then you can replace your `__repr__` method with:

```
def __repr__(self):
    fmtstr = '{first} {last} (#{techid})\nAge: {age} ({bday})\nGPA: {gpa:0.2f} ({credits})'
    bday = self._birthDay.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    return fmtstr.format(first=self._first,
                         last=self._last,
                         age=self.currentAge(),
                         bday=bday,
                         gpa=self.currentGPA(),
                         credits=self._totalCredits)
```

Oh, and since `_birthDay` is now a `datetime.datetime`, you need to update `currentAge()` to return `int((datetime.datetime.now() - self._birthDay) / datetime.timedelta(days=365))` That will be reasonably accurate without being too complicated.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have now added the main and the data file for more clarity.

Comment: @JakeMeyer Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, but if I use this method,, how will I update the if else statements in the def currentAge(self) method?

        if myMonth <= month and myDay <= day:
            return year - myYear
        # If not, it is one year less than the current estimated age.
        else:
            return year - myYear - 1

Comment: `datetime` objects have `year`, `month` and `day` attributes if you want, but you can replace that whole method with the one liner I suggested at the end of my answer if you only care about being reasonably accurate.

Comment: To be clear, you can do `today = datetime.datetime.today()`, then `self._birthDay.month <= today.month`, etc. `dateutil` also has a module `relativedelta` that helps abstract this sort of thing away so you can do `relativedelta(datetime.datetime.today(), self._birthDay).years`

Comment: @JakeMeyer If the problem is answered, you can select one of the answers as accepted by clicking the green arrow under the voting buttons, if you don't know.

Comment: Got it sorry  about that

Comment: @JakeMeyer No problem, glad you got your program working.

Answer (score 2):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#formatspec), not string concatenation, it's *much* cleaner:

```
return "{} {} (# {} ) GPA {:0.2f}".format(
    self._first, self._last, self._techID, self.currentGPA()
)
```

Plus if you use this format, it will auto-convert the type for you

Comment: How should I write the if elif statements then?

Comment: You might consider `'3'.zfill(2)`

Comment: I just noticed that your birthday is sometimes a number. `'{!s:0>2}'.format(3)` Try that on for size.

Comment: We are not allowed to zfill. Is there a way I can use my current if elif statement? Also, I have added my main and getData files so you can see what the program is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, `len` doesn't make sense with an int. If you want the number of characters in it, convert it to an str first.

```
def __repr__(self):
    if len(str(self._birthDay[0]))<2:
        self._birthDay[0] = "0" + str(self._birthDay[0])
    elif len(str(self._birthDay[1]))<2:
        self._birthDay[1] = "0" + str(self._birthDay[1])
    return self._first + " " + self._last + " (#" + self._techID + ")\nAge: " + str(self.currentAge()) + \
           " (" + str(self._birthDay[0]) + "/" + str(self._birthDay[1]) + "/" + str(self._birthDay[2]) + ")" + \
           "\nGPA: %0.2f" % (self.currentGPA()) + " (" + str(self._totalCredits) + " Credits" + ")\n"
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I have now added the main and the data file for more clarity.

Comment: And it is giving me the error

  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Program 6/FINAL/classFile.py", line 84, in __repr__
    self._birthDay[0] = "0" + str(self._birthDay[0])
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment